# how reduce(shorten) code for helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

please help solve the problem.

user factory binding with helper:

```
module Helpers
  def login_user
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :user_status) 
    visit new_user_session_path

    fill_in "user_email", :with => @user.email
    fill_in "user_password", :with => "qwerty"
    click_button "commitSignIn" #OK sign in
  end

  def login_manager
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :manager_status) 
    visit new_user_session_path

    fill_in "user_email", :with => @user.email
    fill_in "user_password", :with => "qwerty"
    click_button "commitSignIn" #OK sign in
  end

  def login_admin
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :admin_status) 
    visit new_user_session_path

    fill_in "user_email", :with => @user.email
    fill_in "user_password", :with => "qwerty"
    click_button "commitSignIn" #OK sign in
  end    
end
```

but this code is not dry. i need reduce it.
my solution:

```
module Helpers
  after(:each) do
    visit new_user_session_path
    fill_in "user_email", :with => @user.email
    fill_in "user_password", :with => "qwerty"
    click_button "commitSignIn" #OK sign in
  end 

  def login_user
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :user_status) 
  end

  def login_manager
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :manager_status) 
  end

  def login_admin
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :admin_status) 
  end    
end
```

but my solution is not worked. console displays follow:

> ```
> kalinin@kalinin ~/rails/phs $ rspec spec/helpers/session_helper_spec.rb
> /home/kalinin/rails/phs/spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb:2:in
> ```
>
> `<module:Helpers>': undefined method`after' for Helpers:Module
>   (NoMethodError)
>         from /home/kalinin/rails/phs/spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb:1:in
>   `'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`after :each` is something RSpec allows for *spec examples*, not arbitrary methods (thus also not for helper methods). (Rails controllers have something similar available with `around_action`, but that, too, is limited to action methods in controllers.)

How about

```
module Helpers
  def login_user(role=:user)
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :"#{role}_status") 
    visit new_user_session_path
    fill_in "user_email", :with => @user.email
    fill_in "user_password", :with => "qwerty"
    click_button "commitSignIn" #OK sign in
  end

  def login_manager
    login_user(:manager)
  end

  def login_admin
    login_user(:admin)
  end
end
```

(untested, so might need some fiddling.)